# how to have a Hover details box in flex 3 similar to ones present in google geomap visualization examples

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, hover

i want to know if there is a already available hover details component similar to the one shown in [google geomap  visualizations examples](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html) which shows city name and its details, or any other similar component that can be used a hover details box.

Answer (score 1):

You could conceivably do this with the Flex framework's own ToolTip class. All standard Flex components (derived from UIComponent) have a toolTip property that's used to create tooltips. The standard tooltip style is black text on a yellow-ish background, but this is easily changed using CSS. For some more elaborate styling, you could use the htmlText property on the TextField within the ToolTip class.

Here are some examples: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_3.html

Comment: Hi , I am using a sprite object, which is not derived from UIComponent class, so i won't be able to use tooltip here.I have tried extending canvas component to have something like this, but it's very very slow. Can u suggest any other way, like some other component i should be extending here. thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any open source component that will do this for you. Creating one yourself isn't hard, but will require some time spent.

Comment: i am thinking along the lines of using css style with createtooltip function , i don't know if it's even possible , but it will be interesting.